# How can we store tables externally to be able to run again the code after a 30 min execution?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, storage

My issue is the app scripts time limit of 30 minutes. My script is longer that 30 min to be completed so I must process it by batches.

I have to store 2D arrays and the iterator to be able to continue during the next running with my previous values stored.
What method could I use to store externally 2D arrays in order to be able to get access to it as easily as possible ?

My table contains about 29 2D arrays of 720k values

Comment: I'm assuming this is with Google Spreadsheet.  Your time out issue may be related to the way you are accessing values in spreadsheet getValue()/setValue() versus getValues()/setValues().  Perhaps if you share your script with us we can advise.

Comment: I'd guess op is using getValues() and setValues() since he is working with 2d arrays.  That's a fair amount of data.  I'd put it into a database and move away from google apps script.

Comment: Actually, I'm using getValues() and setValues(). I can share you the main of my script but not sure it would help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just in case. I'd advice to consider Sheets API (if you don't use it already) instead the GAS. It can work faster. Not to mention that you can save any intermediate date on your HDD (if you're running the script locally).

Comment: You can't store it in Properties Service.  I tried storing 26K characters and it could not hold it.

Comment: What solution can be used to store large array outside ? if Porperties Service doesn't work .. Is it possible to store our arrays in JSON, and use it for the next execution ?

Answer (score 0):

You could append the processed arrays into a Google Sheet, and save the iterator in a [script property](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties). When the script runs it looks for the prop. If it finds it then it uses it, if not, then it starts at the first array. When the script is done it updates the prop.